# Excel there was a problem sending the command to the program

Tags: excel, windows-10, dde

I am getting this error everytime I open MS Excel 2016 in Win 10. I tried unchecking the checkbox "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)" in Advanced options, but still I'm getting this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which can fix effectively this issue. 2 steps :

1. You go to Regedit -> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\Shell\Open :

   - change "ddeexec" key into "ddeexec.old"
   - change "command" key, Default value = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2016\Office16\EXCEL.EXE (%1)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgIaT.png)

At this step, there is no error message. If your workbook still doesn't open, go to step 2 :

2. Right-click on Workbook icon -> Open with -> Choose default program

   - tick on "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"
   - Browse EXCEL.EXE in the right Microsoft Office location (eg. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2016\Office16\EXCEL.EXE)

(When there are many MS Office versions in the PC, the Old location still is set by default).